# Callback for Keras evaluate_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras for one of my experiments. When I use `fit_generator` method I can specify the callbacks so that I can implement after each batch or epoch.

Now, while using evaluate_generator for validation I do following,

One of some other metrics is like below,

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)))
```

The evaluation,

```
metrics = model.evaluate_generator(my_generator(...),
                          steps=steps,
                          use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Here, `my_generator()` `yield` a single input (here batch size is 1). Also, I have multiple types of losses defined in the model. I get all of those losses perfectly.

But the problem is, I get only one evaluation metrics. I think it's the overall metric considering all the single batches as one whole input.

**How can I define a callback or anything like that so that I can do my own calculations on the single batch evaluations?** (like a fit_generator callback).

**Note:** `evaluate_generator` [does not](https://keras.io/models/model/) support callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a lambda callback
https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback

It is also possible to use a complete custom callback.
Example from keras documentation:

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

Comment: Yes, I need any callback. But evaluate_generator does not support callback

Comment: Ahh sorry, I missed that. Seems to be a open issue in Keras.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9484

Comment: No luck then :-( Ok I will try to change my implementations. Thanks for your efforts